# Check for component links in structure groups core service

Tags: core-service

I'm trying to check for component links in structure groups so that I can re-create the linked components with the following code:

```
    public void CheckForComponentLinks(string sgId)
    {
        using (var client = new CoreServiceClient("basicHttp"))
        {
            // Read structure group details
            var structureGroup = (StructureGroupData)client.Read(sgId, new ReadOptions());

            // Get schema fields
            var schemaFields = client.ReadSchemaFields(structureGroup.MetadataSchema.IdRef, true, new ReadOptions());

            // Loop over metadata and check for component links
            foreach (var field in schemaFields.MetadataFields.OfType<ComponentLinkFieldDefinitionData>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Component Link");   
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I've managed to get my console to write out every time it finds a component link, but I need to now get the component data for each one found.

So ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
ComponentData cData = (ComponentData)client.Read(COMPONENT_ID, new ReadOptions());
```

But the problem is I can't get the "COMPONENT_ID" of the component from "field". The only thing I can think of is if I parse the XML that I get back from structureGroup.Metadata and check for tcm Ids?

I've also had a look at [Frank'
s Fields class](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata) but can't see how to get back the tcm Id from ForMetadataOf.

Does anyone know of a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've written a solution to my problem. See code below:

```
    public void CheckForComponentLinks(string sgId)
    {
        using (var client = new CoreServiceClient("basicHttp"))
        {
            // Read structure group details
            var structureGroup = (StructureGroupData)client.Read(sgId, new ReadOptions());

            // Parse metadata to Xml
            var metaData = structureGroup.Metadata;
            XNamespace xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
            var elem = XElement.Parse(metaData);

            // Loop over each tcm id and start check
            foreach (var item in elem.Elements().Where(x => x.Attribute(xlink + "href") != null))
            {
               // Do something here
            }
        }
    }
```

So I'm parsing the Xml and checking for Tcm Ids, works a treat for me!